# What does "calamari" mean?

Tags: the-matrix

In *The Matrix Revolutions* (2003), AK is searching using his computer to (unsuccessfully) scan The Matrix for Niobe and Ghost.

> **Roland:** *Search every pipe, every hole, every crack we know. Sweep as wide as possible, as fast as possible.*
>
> **AK:** *Captain, these lines are crawling with calamari.*

What does "calamari" mean?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Calamari is the term for squid meat generally, so he is referring to the robotic [Sentinels](https://matrix.fandom.com/wiki/Sentinel) (more usually called "squids" or "squiddies") that we see attacking in the films. These occur in the real world, rather than The Matrix of course, one example being the attack on the Nebuchadnezzar in the original Matrix film.

> A sentinel's frightening appearance reminds many humans of squids,
> where they get their nickname of "squiddies". They tend to fly in
> swarms like insects, that can range from a few to thousands.
>
> [image]

Comment: I've taken the liberty of adding a link to the wiki and a nice illustrative picture.

Comment: Yup, that's a nice illustration,  thanks! :)